# Simulating a random walk in Python

Tags: python, random-walk

I am using Python 3. My code below attempts to simulate N steps of a [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) in 3 dimensions. At each step, a random direction is chosen (north, south, east, west, up, down) with 1/6 probability each and a step of size 1 is taken in that direction. The new location is then printed. The starting location is the origin (0,0).

Even though there are no error messages, **the code does not work**. We should move **only** one step either in x, y or z. However, in the output, I see that sometimes I don't move at all or sometimes I move in more than one direction.

Here is my code:

```
import random

N = 30

n = random.random() 

x = 0
y = 0
z = 0
count = 0

while count <= N:

    if n < 1/6:
        x = x + 1          
        n = random.random()
    if n >= 1/6 and n < 2/6:
        y = y + 1           
        n = random.random() 
    if n >= 2/6 and n < 3/6:
        z = z + 1           
        n = random.random() 
    if n >= 3/6 and n < 4/6:
        x = x - 1           
        n = random.random() 
    if n >= 4/6 and n < 5/6:
        y = y - 1          
        n = random.random() 
    if n >= 5/6:
        z = z - 1          
        n = random.random()

    print("(%d,%d,%d)" % (x,y,z))
    count = count + 1

print("squared distance = %d" % (x*x + y*y + z*z))
```

How do you think I can fix the problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `elif` instead of so many ifs. Every time the if is evaluated, the value of n changes and then may qualify for the next if.

Answer (score 2):

Not only should you use `elif`, even for performance, but you don't need the multiple `n = random.random()` statements in the loop -- one will do:

```
import random

N = 30

x = 0
y = 0
z = 0

for _ in range(N):

    n = random.random()

    if n < 1/6:
        x += 1
    elif 1/6 <= n < 2/6:
        y += 1
    elif 2/6 <= n < 3/6:
        z += 1
    elif 3/6 <= n < 4/6:
        x -= 1
    elif 4/6 <= n < 5/6:
        y -= 1
    elif n >= 5/6:
        z -= 1

    print(f"({x},{y},{z})")  # python 3.6ism

print("squared distance = {}".format(x*x + y*y + z*z))
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless the version of Python you are using, you need to implement the answer provided by @cdlane.

If you are using Python 2.X your other problem is that Python is interpreting your numbers as `ints`. To fix that you need to add `.` to the denominator i.e.

`if n < 1/6.:`

instead of

`if n < 1/6:`

`1/6` and other fractions are interpreted as `ints` - you can check it yourself by typing `print 1/6` which will give you `0` or printing the actual type with `print type(1/6)` - which will yield `<type 'int'>`.

Because of that when you run your program all your `n`s will satisfy only the last condition (all will be greater than 0).

Comment: This is actually probably not the case, given the behavior we're seeing. They're probably using Python 3, where 1/6 is evaluated with float division. If this were integer division, each loop would decrease z by 1 and change nothing else.

Comment: @Jeremy McGibbon I'll erase it if it doesn't help - worked for my like a charm (on Python 2.7) - tested for the whole problem.

Comment: This change doesn't help for me, tested on Python 3.5. Make sure you aren't getting any lines where two numbers change (e.g. `(-7,-2,2)` to `(-7,-1,1)`.

Comment: I tried your solution, used `float(6)`, and it's not sufficient for Python 2 as the output still had incorrect double moves like, `(-4,1,2)` followed by `(-5,2,2)` instead of only one move of step size 1.

Comment: Ok, @cdlane - just saw it and saw your answer. Right indeed. Of course it's going to enter other ifs! I just saw the conversion issues and that caught my eye immediately.